# Ruby - Passing array variable to method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flickr

I'm having trouble passing an array variables to a method in rails. I'm using the flickraw gem and want to link a user's NSID to their username but it's returning with the error,

> "'flickr.people.getInfo' - User not found"

I've output the variables to the cli and tested each one individually. Can see each NSID so can't understand why I'm getting the error.

Here's my code

```
require "flickraw"

class PhotosController < ApplicationController

def index
    @list = flickr.photos.getRecent(:per_page => '3')
    @list.each do |info|
        store = [info.owner]
        for i in 0..store.length
            person = flickr.people.getInfo(:user_id => store[i])
            puts person.username
        end
    end
end
end
```

Here's the links to Flickraw and Flickr-api docs,
[Flickraw docs](http://hanklords.github.io/flickraw/FlickRaw/Flickr/People.html#method-i-getInfo), [flickr-api docs](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.people.getInfo.html)

Any help is always appreciated.

Comment: Note that you are creating and traversing a one-element array, which is somewhat pointless. Just call `flickr.people.getInfo(user_id: info.owner)` and remove the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for i in 0..store.length
```

this range is *inclusive*. You should use exclusive range (note three dots):

```
for i in 0...store.length
```

For inclusive range, there appear to be `length + 1` iterations, and for the last one the respective array has no index, returns `nil` and everything fails.

---

Another option would be to use the inclusive range till `length - 1`:

```
for i in 0..store.length-1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm quite new to ruby and didn't even realise there were inclusive and exclusive. I must read up on it.

Comment: Darragh, three dots versus two can be easy to miss. For that reason some of us prefer to stick with two dots. Here we would write `for i in 0..store.length-1`. By the way, most Rubiests *never* use `for` loops. Here they might write `store.length.times { |i| <code> }`. One advantage of using an enumerator with a block is that the variable `i` is not visible outside the block.